# Typescript vs Tsc vs Ntypescript

Tags: angular, typescript

This all started with `tsc --init` not working...

What's the difference between:

```
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g tsc
npm install -g ntsc
```

I thought "tsc" was just a shortcut for typescript, but listing them out seems to give different versions

> PS C:\angular2-app> npm list -g tsc
>   C:\Users\Wheeeeee\AppData\Roaming\npm
>   └── tsc@1.20150623.0
>
> PS C:\angular2-app> npm list -g typescript
>   C:\Users\Wheeeeee\AppData\Roaming\npm
>   └── typescript@1.8.10

So, what's the difference between the two. Is typescript the library and tsc some sort of a command line helper?

P.S. I don't really care about [ntsc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntypescript), it's just part of the question if you know offhand or for some reason think it's a must. Ignore otherwise.

EDIT: Given the answer below, how does powershell know which tsk I am trying to use? How do I specify?

Comment: You probably want to use the regular `typescript`. This `tsc` thing seems to be deprecated and points to this `ntypescript` which can be useful if you want to use typescript as a service, and if you don't need that then just use typescript.

Comment: To be sure I understand, ntypescript is for times when the tsc compiler is not available on the platform, and therefore is used as a remote service instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`tsc` is some package with the same name as the typescript compiler on the command line. `typescript` is the real TypeScript package.

Answer (score 2):

For `"tsc": "latest"` from https://github.com/basarat/tsc:

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc --help
Version 1.5.3
```

For `"ntypescript": "latest"` from https://github.com/basarat/ntypescript:

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc --help
Version 2.5.0
```

For `"typescript": "latest"` from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript:

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc --help
Version 4.0.2
```

They are lineage of the same code base. Earlier it was baked by https://github.com/basarat and then it started to be sponsored by Microsoft https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript

So use `"typescript": "latest"` is the most advanced, just forget about other options ))

Also the list for `--target` & `--lib` is the most updated for `"typescript": "latest"`.